# Ng-style for multiple lined span

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a tree structure and the names on span can be very long.

```
<div class="level" ng-show="cond">
    <span>{{level7.name}}</span>    
</div>
```

css:

```
left: 14px;
position: relative;
```

So, i try to write a ng-style directive for span in multiple lined state. Is there any way to detect in angular when a span is multiple lined or not?

Comment: Create a directive to check the height of the span. If it is more than required that means it is multiple lines. You can also invoke a method from the directive.

Comment: Do you want to create Tree view for this?

Comment: @@Bhojendra its not decisive how many chars will fit for one line @@Aakash Its good idea but can't we just check it inline in html? Maher no

Comment: In directive check the height of one character and if the height of the content is highter then that then it mean that it's multiline.